# Convert Application back to Virtual Directory in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, virtual-directory

This is really simple if IIS6 but I can't seem to figure out how to convert an Application back into a Virtual Directory in IIS7 without having to delete it and recreate it from scratch.

Answer (score 13):

The wording is scary but "Remove" converts it back to a regular folder.  It doesn't actually delete the folder itself as you may assume.  So, the command is still in the right-click on the vdir itself.

Comment: yes, but if the fodler doesn't exist in that parent's directory structure, it disappears for good and you have to go through and add it back in manually as a Virtual Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right-click the application and click to remove button. This will convert back to the Virtual Directory.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrC09.png

Comment: Why are folders being converted to applications when we don't even want them to be? we have to keep going through and deleting the applications that have been created in the subfolders when we want them to be just folders?

Comment: It shouldn't create a virtual application in IIS until you do that.

Comment: When we load up in VS it creates some of the subprojects as applications when we don't want them and in a project with 140 sub projects removing them is a pain and keeps being forgotton, We just want to know why it is being made as an application and can we stop it.

Comment: I believe you are referring to Visual studio with VS.  That is another issue and you will need to check logs for this.